# Method in class cannot be applied to given types - using action listeners

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a method that uses `ActionEvent` such as:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    if (command.equals("Clear Fields")) {
        clearFields();
    }
    else if (command.equals("Add Mobile")) {
        addGadget();
    }
    else if (command.equals("Add MP3")) {
        addGadget();
    }   
}
```

And the method I wish to execute such as:

```
public void addGadget(Gadget theGadget)
{
    gadgets.add(theGadget);
}
```

The error is in the `actionPerformed` method with `addGadget();`. Is this something to do with the parameters? I have tried adding the parameters in as they are in the method I wish to execute, but I still get errors.

If the command is equal to `"Add Mobile"`, I want to execute the `addGadget` method. But I am getting above error. Why is this?

Comment: The method `public void addGadget(Gadget theGadget)` expects a parameter of type `Gadget`. But in your listener you don't provide one: `addGadget();`

Comment: If I do `addGadget(Gadget)` I still get errors, but this time it's because Gadget isn't assigned - is this a mistake I have made earlier on?

Comment: You need an actual **instance** of a `Gadget` object, which you have to pass to this method. Depending on how you create your gadgets, it should look something like this: `Gadget gadget = new Gadget(); addGadget(gadget);`

Comment: @August well if you want to call you addGadget method you have to pass it the Gadget that you want to add. Where and how you create that Gadget is something that you should know yourself.

Comment: I know how the gadget is created - I am just struggling with passing it as a parameter.

Comment: I really don't get what your problem is. If you have created your gadged object then what is the problem in passing it? it's literally just writing the variable name into parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the surprise accept :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to invoke that method without providing the required Gadget parameter.

So, you either have to somehow provide a parameter, or you have to change the signature of the method you intend to call.